# Jade button onClick not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I currently have a file in jade and I'm attempting to make a form where if the user clicks on the submit button after filling out the question's answer, then it runs a JavaScript function. However, for some reason, it is not able to find the function in the file for some reason.

Below is my Jade code:

```
script(language='JavaScript').
  function checkAnswer() {
    var answer = document.getElementById('sessionID').value.toLowerCase();
      if(answer == '4') {
        console.log('Correct!');
      }
      else {
        console.log('Sorry, try again!');
      }
  }

extends ../layout

block content
  .page-header
    h3 Challenge #1
  p 2 + 2 = ?
  input(type='text', name='sessionID', value=valueID)
  input(type='button', value='Submit', onclick='checkAnswer()')
```

This returns the error code:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: checkAnswer is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong? It must be something really stupid :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it with the help of the person above - even though others say it wasnt specific enough to help, it was good enough for me :)

Here is how you would fix that. Since its outside of the "block" simply move the script into the block and it will now be compiled into HTML from Jade. Personally, I also moved the JS to a different file and instead of describing the function right in the jade file I moved it to another JS and included it in the jade file with the line

```
script(type='text/javascript' src='answers.js')
```

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the script inside some block for it to be inserted in the resulting html file.

Comment: Even though it may be the correct thought of an answer, it is not at all helpful. "some block" doesn't help. You should just add a bit more information. Otherwise, your answer may indeed be deleted.

Comment: I'm asuming the OP has read [this](http://jade-lang.com/reference/extends/). He knows what a block is. And I am clearly stating that, yes, he needs to put his script tag inside of some `block`, like his `content` block, for it to be including in the resulting html file. I also asumed he knows that to be able to register a function as an event handler it needs to be declared in the page beforehand, which it is not the way he is writing it. I thought it was helpful. Better than pestering people about this shit instead of posting a better one.